# what's the cache size and block size?

Tags: caching

I have this information

```
clock_rate(Ghz): 2
mem_access_latency(cycles): 250
L1_size(Bytes): 4096
L1_line_size(Bytes): 16
set_associativity: 2
```

in this information,

what's the cache size and blcok size?

and is it same to line_size and block size?

Answer (score 2):

I can understand why this confusion. Lot of resources use cache, line, block terminology. After going through most of them, this is true to my knowledge.

`Cache size = Cache capacity`. In given info, `L1_size(Bytes): 4096 Bytes`

`Block size= Cache block size = cache line size = line size`. In given info, `16 Bytes`